Uglify JS minification with React Native is giving me error: property __r doesn't exist
In a React Native CLI App I have the following metro.config.js.
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const { mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
config.transformer.minifierPath = 'metro-minify-uglify';
config.transformer.minifierConfig = {
    compress: {
        // The option below removes all console logs statements in production.
        drop_console: true,

    },
    mangle: {
        // mangle options
        toplevel: true,
        eval: true,

        properties: {
            // mangle property options
        }
    },
    output: {
        // output options
        beautify: true,
    },
};

const config2 = {};

module.exports = mergeConfig(config, config2);

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

 cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleDebug && cd ..
adb install .\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Uglify minification is doing the job. But when I build and run app it give me error
I get error:
property __r doesn't exist
I looked online but couldn't find anything. I tried terser the result is worse, still contains property names.
I tried Uglify minification and expected the build to still run, but it didn't Got error: " property __r doesn't exist"
How to solve this error?
I notice this at the bottom of the index.android.bundle
__r(148);
__r(0);

Tried removing it, but didn't help, got me new error: "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly"
Am using:
 "metro-minify-uglify": "^0.76.8",

